# Display just one legend for two plots with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a chart using the "plot" two times. But I need the legend only appears one time because it is the same legend for the two plots. Here's the code with an example:

```
# data
example_data = {'x': [-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                'y': [10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 14, 15, 17, 18, 21, 23, 23, 24]}
df = pd.DataFrame(example_data)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot('x', 'y', data=df.query('x < 0'), marker='o', color='b', label='something') # the legend I want to show in the chart
plt.plot('x', 'y', data=df.query('x > 0'), marker='o', color='b')
plt.legend();
```

This code results in the following chart:

[image]

(here I have only one line because it is just an example. In my original chart I have more than one, so I need the legend)

As you can see, when I call "plt.legend()" it activates the legend for the two plots. So my question is: how can I show just one of the them?

Comment: is it not using`label=''` (empty string) ?

Comment: There's a weird trick in matplotlib. Try `label='_no_legend'`

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno and Paul H. Both worked. I had no ideia of the trick '_no_legend'. Apparently it works like the empty string that Bruno suggested. Thank you again!

Comment: Normally if you don't set `label` you won't get a legend either, but in this case you are using a string `'y'` to access the `data` object, so Matplotlib uses that as a default label, whether you like it or not.

Comment: It should be noted, the point at x=0 is not plotted.

Comment: Trenton Mckinney yes, that's exactly the intention with this plot.

Comment: I put an answer to help people having the same problem to not have to read the remarks and because an answer is not visible. But perhaps it is better you answer yourself ? In that case say me and I delete my answer

Comment: I appreciate it. You can keep your answer, Bruno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first way is to use an empty string for the *label*:

```
plt.plot('x', 'y', data=df.query('x > 0'), marker='o', color='b', label='')
```

A second way given by [Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) is to use the trick '_no_legend' for the *label*:

```
plt.plot('x', 'y', data=df.query('x > 0'), marker='o', color='b', label='_no_legend')
```

Both ways hide the label, for instance :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# data
example_data = {'x': [-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                'y': [10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 14, 15, 17, 18, 21, 23, 23, 24]}
df = pd.DataFrame(example_data)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot('x', 'y', data=df.query('x < 0'), marker='o', color='b', label='something') # the legend I want to show in the chart
plt.plot('x', 'y', data=df.query('x > 0'), marker='o', color='b', label='') # the legend to not show
plt.legend();
fig.show();
```

produces :
[image]